# Thread control block in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

What is the structure used for saving thread state like PC, SP and registers during thread context switch in linux? The equivalent of TCB in freebsd. If possible please point to the source file [here](http://lxr.linux.no/linux).

Note that PCB itself is not enough, as we have PC, SP etc. per thread not per process.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's actually `task_struct`. In Linux, a task can be a thread, a process, or something in between. A thread is just the name you give to a task that shares most things (VMA's, file descriptors, etc...) with other tasks.

This is much in line with the idea that a thread is just a particular kind of process, and can be handled via the same functions, etc... Plan 9's `rfork()` and Linux's `clone()` allow to create a process with a customizable level of sharing, so you end up using the same machinery to create processes and threads.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want [setcontext](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setcontext) and friends (but your code won't be very portable, and tricky to get right)?

Or are you talking from inside the kernel? Then perhaps [task_struct](http://linuxgazette.net/133/saha.html) could be what you look for??

Comment: Yes - I am looking for the later - But I am not sure task_struct's thread_info is the right thing, as it doesn't seem to have any structure to store registers during a context switch. In fact task_struct is exactly the PCB.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but from the `task_struct` you probably can get the representation of an address space, and from an address space, the list of *thread tasks* having it?